# Where does the problematic borrow happen?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrowing

```
pub struct Dest<'a> {
    pub data: Option<&'a i32>,
}

pub struct Src<'a> {
    pub data: Option<&'a i32>,
}

pub trait Flowable<'a: 'b, 'b> {
    fn flow(&'a self, dest: &mut Dest<'b>);
}

impl<'a: 'b, 'b> Flowable<'a, 'b> for Src<'a> {
    fn flow(&self, dest: &mut Dest<'b>) {
        dest.data = self.data;
    }
}

struct ContTrait<'a, 'b> {
    pub list: Vec<Box<Flowable<'a, 'b> + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a: 'b, 'b> Flowable<'a, 'b> for ContTrait<'a, 'b> {
    fn flow(&'a self, dest: &mut Dest<'b>) {
        for flowable in self.list.iter() {
            flowable.flow(dest);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x1 = 15;
    let x2 = 20;
    let mut c = ContTrait { list: Vec::new() };

    let mut dest = Dest { data: Some(&x2) };
    c.list.push(Box::new(Src { data: Some(&x1) }));
    c.flow(&mut dest);
}
```

I'm struggling to implement passing a reference from one struct to another struct. Everytime I progress a little bit, there will be a new block. What I want to achieve looks trivial in language like C++, for type Src, a trait Flowable is defined if certain condition is met, a reference in A will be passed to type Dest. I have played for a while with lifetime specifier to make Rust compiler happy. Now I also implement same trait for type ContTrait which is a collection of Flowable and this ContTrait also implment trait Flowable to iterate every object in it and call flow. This is a simplied case for real world usage.

I just can't figure out why Rust compiler reports

```
error[E0597]: `c` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:38:5
   |
38 |   c.flow(&mut dest);
   |   ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
39 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `c` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `c` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `ContTrait<'_, '_>
```

Comment: Please run `rustfmt` next time. Also make sure, that the line number in the error match your actual line numbers in the example.

Comment: I see a lot of `<'a: 'b, 'b>`. That is redundant and can be replaced by `<'a>` and replace all `'b` with `'a`.

Comment: *"What I want to achieve looks trivial in language like C++[.]"* I doubt it. [Here's the nearest I could get in C++](https://onlinegdb.com/BJQ9UHdlN) to the [corrected Rust code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=414e5e99b2735a260001a10f6edfc9e1). You're probably thinking of something simpler, which *would* be easier in C++, but has a little more friction in Rust, like requiring some `unsafe { ... }` or lots of `.clone()`s.

Comment: (And furthermore, the C++ version is still fragile; [for example, you could do this](https://onlinegdb.com/SJmLjBdxN). The explicit lifetimes in the Rust version are exactly what make it safe. For the most part, Rust's lifetimes just formalize rules that also exist in C++ -- they're just enforced by you instead of by Rust.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> pub trait Flowable<'a: 'b, 'b> {
>     fn flow(&'a self, dest: &mut Dest<'b>);
> }
> ```

The `&'a self` here is at the core of the problem. It says that the object `flow` is called on must outlive the lifetime `dest` is parametrized with.

In `main`, you do

```
c.flow(&mut dest);
```

and `dest` is implicitly parametrized with the lifetime of `x2`. Since you call `flow` on `c`, you imply that `c` must outlive `x2`, which it doesn't.

If you remove the `'a` bound on the self reference in the trait definition and the `ContTrait` impl, the code compiles.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion and explanation.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: You propably don't want to use `&'a self`, most of the time. There are some legit cases, e.g. where the return value of a function depends on `self` and the compiler can't figure it out, but normally `&self` is all you ever want.